# Ruby: XML to JSON tree parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, json, parsing

I have following XML:

```
<fruits>
    <fruit>APPLE</fruit>
    <fruit>PEACH</fruit>
    <fruit>BANANA</fruit>
</fruits>
```

When I parse it to JSON or object I get following:

```
{
    "fruits": {
        "fruit": [
            'APPLE', 'PEACH', 'BANANA'
        ]
    }
}
```

But I want following:

```
{
    "fruits": [ 'APPLE', 'PEACH', 'BANANA' ]
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: show the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in XmlSimple called "GroupTags" that is intended to do what you want in an XML-to-Hash conversion. It appears to work when the tag you want grouped is NOT the root.

For example, if your xml actually has a different root element in it:

```
<root>
 <fruits>
  <fruit>APPLE</fruit>
  <fruit>PEACH</fruit>
  <fruit>BANANA</fruit>
 </fruits>
</root>
```

Then you can do the following:

```
options = {
           'ForceArray' => false, 
           'GroupTags' => {'fruits'=>'fruit'}
          }
XmlSimple.xml_in(xml, options)

#=> {"fruits"=>["APPLE", "PEACH", "BANANA"]}
```

Which corresponds to the JSON you are looking for.

Unfortunately, if `<fruits>` is your root element, the `GroupTags` option doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(<<XML)
<fruits>
  <fruit>APPLE</fruit>
  <fruit>PEACH</fruit>
  <fruit>BANANA</fruit>
</fruits>
XML

results =
  xml.xpath('/*').map{|parent|
    [ parent.name,
      parent.xpath('*').map{|child| child.text } ] }

puts JSON.pretty_unparse(Hash[results])
```